# Showing that $\mathbb{E}[Xg(Y) \mid Y] = g(Y) \mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I got stuck on this problem where I have to show that, for discret random variables $X$ and $Y$ and a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Xg(Y)\mid Y] = g(Y)\;\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]
\end{align}
where the probability for every value in $\text{Im}(X)$ and $\text{Im}(Y)$ is always nonzero.

## my attempt

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Xg(Y) | Y=y] &= \sum_{z \,\in \,\mathrm{Im}(Xg(Y))}z \:\mathbb{P}(Xg(Y) = z \mid Y=y)\\
&= \sum_{z \,\in \,\mathrm{Im}(Xg(Y))}z \:\frac{\mathbb{P}(Xg(Y)=z, Y=y)}{\mathbb{P}(Y=y)}\\
&= \sum_{z \,\in \,\mathrm{Im}(Xg(Y))}z \:\frac{\mathbb{P}(Xg(y)=z, Y=y)}{\mathbb{P}(Y=y)}\\
&\vdots \: (?)\\
&= g(y) \sum_{x\in \mathrm{Im}(X)} \mathbb{P}(X=x\mid Y=y)
\end{align}

but I don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: You only need to care about those $y$ such that $Y = y$ has positive probability.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you for the tip, but how could I rewrite the sum in such a way that it is equal to the final result?

Comment: More generally, this follows from $g(Y)$ being $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and the "pulling out what is known" property of conditional expectation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two competing definitions of the condition expectation and you haven't specified which one so I will assume you mean
$$
E(X \mid A) = \frac{1}{P(A)} E(X \mathbf{1}_A),
$$
where $A$ is an event of positive probability. You seem to be using this definition since you are dealing with discrete random variables.

Fix $y$ such that $Y = y$ has positive probability. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
E(Xg(Y) \mid Y = y) &= \frac{1}{P(Y = y)} E \left(Xg(Y) \mathbf{1}_{\{Y = y\}} \right) \\
&= g(y) \frac{E \left(X \mathbf{1}_{\{Y = y\}} \right)}{P(Y = y)} \\
&= g(y) E(X \mid Y = y),
\end{align*}
$$
which proves the desired result. (Note that we used that $g(Y) = g(y)$ on the event where $Y = y,$ and that this is a constant value, so it comes out of the expectation.)

**Observation.** In fact, we proved the result for *any* $X$ (not necessarily discrete) and on the atoms of *any* $Y,$ that is, the $y$ such that $P(Y = y)$ is positive.